# Data from Android Database not being read

Tags: android, database

I'm working on an app for taking basketball stats but I have run into a little problem and have been unable to solve it. The part I'm having trouble with is when you add a player to the team, it is supposed to insert all of their info into the database. Then, you should be able to hit the refresh button and have it show all of the players, but instead it just displays an empty line of text. There is also no error that being posted to the stack traces, which makes finding the problem even harder.

Database file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class StatbookDB {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TEAMNAME = "team_name";
    public static final String KEY_PLAYERS = "number_of_players";
    public static final String KEY_PNUMBER = "players_number";
    public static final String KEY_MASCOT = "team_mascot";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "team_gender";
    public static final String KEY_PNAME = "players_name";
    public static final String KEY_2PTSMK= "field_goals_made";
    public static final String KEY_2PTSMIS = "field_goals_missed";
    public static final String KEY_2PTSTOTAL = "total_field_goals";
    public static final String KEY_3PTSMK = "made_3pts";
    public static final String KEY_3PTSMIS = "missed_3pts";
    public static final String KEY_3PTSTOTAL = "total_3pts";
    public static final String KEY_FTAT = "free_throws_attempted";
    public static final String KEY_FTMK = "free_throws_missed";
    public static final String KEY_FTTOTAL = "free_throws_total";
    public static final String KEY_OREB = "offensive_rebounds";
    public static final String KEY_DREB = "defensive_rebounds";
    public static final String KEY_ASSISTS = "player_assits";
    public static final String KEY_FOULS = "player_fouls";
    public static final String KEY_TURNOVERS = "player_turnovers";
    public static final String KEY_BLOCKS = "player_blocks";
    public static final String KEY_STEALS = "player_steals";
    public static final String KEY_INOUT = "in_or_out";

    private String DATABASE_NTTABLE = "";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BasketballStats";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLET = "teams";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLEH = "hometeam";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLEA = "awayteam";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLET + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_TEAMNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MASCOT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );
            /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEH + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_PNUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_PNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSMIS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSMIS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_FTMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FTAT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FTTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_OREB + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DREB + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ASSISTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FOULS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TURNOVERS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_BLOCKS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_STEALS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_INOUT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLET);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public StatbookDB(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public StatbookDB open() {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase= ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long addTeam(String teamName, String teamMascot, String Gender) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TEAMNAME, teamName);
        cv.put(KEY_MASCOT, teamMascot);
        cv.put(KEY_GENDER, Gender);
        DATABASE_NTTABLE = teamName.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        ourDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NTTABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_PNUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_PNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSMIS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_2PTSTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSMIS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_3PTSTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_FTMK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FTAT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FTTOTAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_OREB + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DREB + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ASSISTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FOULS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TURNOVERS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_BLOCKS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_STEALS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_INOUT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLET, null, cv);
    }
    public String[] countTeams(String[] teams) {
        String [] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TEAMNAME};
        Cursor c  = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLET, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iTeam = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEAMNAME);
        List<String> teams3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            String s = c.getString(iTeam);
            int i = c.getInt(iRow);
            teams3.add(s);
        }
        String[] teams2 = new String[teams3.size()];
        teams3.toArray(teams2);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return teams2;
    }

    public String getPlayers(String teamName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String TABLE = teamName.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).replaceAll(" ", "_");
        String [] columns = {KEY_PNUMBER, KEY_PNAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iNum = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PNUMBER);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PNAME);
        if (c.getCount()!= 0){
            try {
                for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iNum) + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\n";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            result = "No players added to this team yet";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public long addPlayer(String playerName, int playerNumber, String teamName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int dValue = 0;
        String dbTable = teamName.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).replaceAll(" ", "_");
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_PNUMBER, playerNumber);
        cv.put(KEY_PNAME, playerName);
        cv.put(KEY_2PTSMK, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_2PTSMIS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_2PTSTOTAL, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_3PTSMK, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_3PTSMIS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_3PTSTOTAL, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_FTMK, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_FTAT, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_FTTOTAL, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_OREB, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_DREB, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_ASSISTS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_FOULS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_TURNOVERS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_BLOCKS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_STEALS, dValue);
        cv.put(KEY_INOUT, "out");
        return ourDatabase.insert(dbTable, null, cv);
    }
}
```

File adding and displaying players

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TeamView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TabHost th;
    TabSpec ts;
    Button addPlayer, refresh;
    EditText Pname, Pnum;
    TextView showPlayers, tName;
    String teamName, players, teamNameUN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teamview);
        Initialize();
        Bundle getTeam = getIntent().getExtras();
        teamName = getTeam.getString("team");
        teamNameUN = getTeam.getString("teamUN");
        th.setup();
        ts = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        ts.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        ts.setIndicator("View Team");
        th.addTab(ts);
        ts = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        ts.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        ts.setIndicator("Add Player");
        th.addTab(ts);
        tName.setText(teamName);
        StatbookDB count = new StatbookDB(this);
        count.open();
        players = count.getPlayers(teamNameUN);
        count.close();
        showPlayers.setText(players);
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        addPlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAddPlayer);
        refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRefresh);
        Pname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPName);
        Pnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPNum);
        showPlayers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowPlayers);
        tName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTname);
        addPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bAddPlayer:
            String playerName = Pname.getText().toString();
            String plNum = Pnum.getText().toString();
            int playerNumber;
            playerNumber = Integer.parseInt(plNum);
            StatbookDB entry = new StatbookDB(this);
            entry.open();
            entry.addPlayer(playerName, playerNumber, teamNameUN);
            entry.close();
            break;

        case R.id.bRefresh:
            StatbookDB count = new StatbookDB(this);
            count.open();
            players = count.getPlayers(teamNameUN);
            count.close();
            showPlayers.setText(players);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please try `showPlayers.invalidate()` after you use 
`showPlayers.setText(players)` in the refresh button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem lie in `getPlayers` function of `StatbookDB` class: 
`for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){` 
while the it should be `for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){`
the loop expression is reverse
beside of that, you should include `KEY_ROWID` in your `columns` so it will be `String [] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_PNUMBER, KEY_PNAME};` because you get it later

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't even realised that.  I spent about 3 hours last night trying to figure out what I had done wrong.  I can't believe it was just a simple exclamation point that was missing.  Thanks, again.